# When I use Socket.IO, why I got an error An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException'

Tags: c#, sockets, socket.io

I coded a program to get the screen shot and send to the server. Every time, I got a screenshot and turned into base64 then sent it using Socket.IO. (using SocketIOClient.dll)

```
 Dictionary<string, string> image = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 image.add("image", "");

 private void windowMonitorTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

     image["image"] = windowMonitorManager.MonitorScreen();
     client.getSocket().Emit("Shot", image);
 }
```

windowMonitorManager.MonitorScreen() is for return a base64 string. If I do not use `client.getSocket().Emit("Shot", image)`, the program could run correct, but if I add this line, the program stop like 2 seconds(send nearly 80 times) and give me the error :

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

If I do not send the string as long as this, just a short string "hello", it sends 1600 times then occurs the same problem.

Somebody knows how to debug this problem?

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I try to test socket.Emit(), and find it has its limit.

For example, I send a string of 10000000, after 88 times, it occurs the out of memory problem.
If I send a string of 5000000, after 170 times, it occurs the same problem.

Comment: Do you have the full stack trace for the `System.OutOfMemoryException`?

Comment: @PaulWilliams, How to trace the full stack using c#?

Comment: @cindywmiao What IDE are you using? Visual Studio? It should have a debug option, where you can insert breakpoints and get verbose errors

Comment: You can try a `try`/`catch` around your `client.GetSocket().Emit()` call, trap all `Exceptions`, and print or save or somehow view `exception.ToString()`.  But that is not necessarily going to work, because the program could be running out of memory.  If you debug the program, you should be able to see the exception when it happens and see the full stack trace.

Comment: @PaulWilliams I debug like what you said, I could not catch the exception.

Comment: I don't know SocketIOClient.dll but maybe you have to close the socket after using?

Comment: this smells like the server never gets a end of message an keeps adding everything to the same image until it gets out of memory.Post your server code I bet the issue is in there.

Comment: @Pedro.The.Kid I do not think it's server issue, because if I use mac client to send the data, it's ok. Only window client occurs the issue.

Comment: @habakuk I could not close socket, because I continue using it all the time.

Comment: you say that you send 80 images in 2 seconds how often does the windowMonitorTimer_Tick is fired? I doubt you could send 40fps. What is happening is you are trying to send to many images to fast and the out buffer is blowing up.

Comment: @cindywmiao The question I have is if `client.getSocket()`gives you the same socket every time you call it or if it gives you a new socket on every call. If it gives you a new socket you have to close and dispose this socket after using.

Comment: How big is the image?

Comment: Looks like `client.getSocket()` creates a new object each time. Maybe try to assign the result of client.getSocket() to a private field.

Comment: If it works on MAC but doesn't work on Windows, then tweaking the address space settings in the boot.config can be of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of memory is mostly an exception thrown when the process consumes much larger memory than what is allowed by default system (like 2 GB on a 32 bit system), on a 64 bit system, it is higher, but is still bound by the certain practical limit, it's not the theory value of 2^64, it differs from OS to OS and is also dependent on underlying RAM, but is large enough for a single process, now this situation can happens due to multiple reasons:

- Memory leak (most prominent), mostly associated with the unmanaged code calls, if there's a handle or memory allocation that is not de-allocated or freed, over a period of time it leads to huge memory allocation for a process and thus the exception, when system cannot map any more.
- Managed code can too leak and I have done that, when objects gets continuously created and they are not de-referenced, i.e they are still reachable in GC context, so you can lead to this scenario, I have done this in my code :)
- This is not a null reference or a corruption, so taking direct stack trace will be of little use in this scenario, simply because you may get a different stack every time, it will be like the stack of the process threads, when exception happens and it would be mostly misleading, so do not try that way. Executing method of a thread doesn't mean it caused memory leak and it will be different for different threads.

How to debug:

Number of simple steps can be taken to narrow down, but before anything ensure that you have the debug version with valid pdb files for all the loaded binaries of the process.

- To know whether is it a leak, monitor process "working set", "virtual bytes" counters either via task manager or preferably via perfmon, since it is much more accurate, also it provides visual graph.
- Now a leak is a leak, so steps like increasing address space in a 32 bit system to 3 GB in place of default 2 GB can only help for sometime, but perfmon will tell you if there's a stabilization point, like in few cases, process needs 2.2 GB of memory, so 2 GB by default is not enough but 3 GB in boot.config and UserVA setting for fine tuning 3 GB will help avoiding exception.

  - If you are using 64 bit system then that's not a worry point, but ensure that your binary is compiled for X64 or any CPU, a 32 bit binary will run as a WOW process and will have limitation on 64 bit system too.
  - Also try a small utility handles from sysinternals, running it mutliple times in a batch for a process will provide details of a leaking handle, in terms of number of handles like file, mutex etc allocated
  - Once you have confirmed a genuine leak, not a settings or configuration or system issue, then comes the memory profilers. In free ones, you get lot of information through free tools like windbg, umdh and leakdiag, they infact point you to exact stack trace which is leaking. umdh and leakdiag are both very good tools, they let you know the leaking function. Leakdiag is more exhaustive than UMDH, but for runtime heap UMDH is good enough
- Professional memory profilers like:
- Dot Memory - http://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/
- Ants - Red Gate - http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/

are also very good, i personally find Dot memory much more helpful and it helps in quickly pointing to the leaking function or type, with little effort, provided you have correct symbol files. Both have free download version available

Mostly resolving out of memory exception is a gradual and iterative process, because this one could be hidden deep inside, leaking a chunk memory with every execution and bringing the complete process to knees. Let me know if you need help in using a specific tool, then we can see what more can be done to debug the issue further. Happy Debugging

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like there's a bug in the `SocketIOClient` DLL. Without the DLL I cannot reproduce the problem, but tracking it down sounds easy.

Since C# is a garbage collected language, the only way to get an Out Of Memory (OOM) is if you have too much memory allocated that cannot be tracked down to a 'root object'. There are several kinds of root objects:

- Static variables (or threadstatic)
- Methods variables (locals / arguments) in your stack trace

All objects that you reference from these two (direct / indirect) will contribute to your memory pressure. If you allocate memory that's not available, the GC will first attempt to free memory before throwing an OOM; if not enough memory is free after the GC completed, an OOM will be thrown.

One obvious reason why this might happen is because you're running a 32-bit process, which is the default in Visual Studio nowadays. This can be fixed in the project properties. However, most processes don't need more than 2 GB of memory, so it's more likely that you 'leaked' memory somewhere. So let's break it down:

**Locals or arguments that leak**

Ways to solve these kind of OOM:

1. Open visual studio, ctrl d,e (or debug -> exceptions)
2. Click OutOfMemoryException -> check the 'throw' box
3. Run the program.

When the out of memory (OOM) hits, you browse through the nodes in the stack trace (or 'parallel stacks') and check the size of the variables. In most cases it's a single buffer or collection that causes the problem. F.ex. in your case a buffer might fill up with socket data, which is never emptied.

**Static variables that leak**

Other cases of OOM are usually buffers that granually fill up and have a reference to the main tree. The easiest way to find these is to use a memory profiler, like Red Gate / ANTS memory profiler. Run your program in the profiler, take some snapshots and check for 'large instances'.

In general, I usually try to avoid static variables alltogether, which solves a whole world of problems.

**Oh and in this case...**

Perhaps it's worth noting that there are a lot of good socket libraries out there... even though I don't know the specifics of SocketIOClient, you might want to consider using a widely supported, proven socket library like WCF/SOAP or Protobuf. There's a lot of material online on how to use these in just about any scenario, so if the problem is in SocketIOClient you might want to consider that...

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you are running your timer too frequently and eating memory to an unsustainable point. Did you try lowering its frequency?

If lowering the frequency doesn't help, your code or the SocketIOClient.dll library may be leaking memory. I suggest that first you review the usage of that library to verify that you are not leaving resources open.